# Solid angle on a sphere of the intersection of multiple hemispheres

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-geometry

Consider the following scenario where I have a unit sphere cut by $N$ halfplanes that all contain the center of the sphere, thus forming several hemispheres. How can I calculate the solid angle subtended by the intersection of those hemispheres?

[image]

The problem is trivial when $N=2$, but what about arbitrary $N$ (I have a practical problem that requires me to solve for the case when $N=4$)? The intersection area is a spherical convex polygon(is it?), so is there a closed-form solution like calculating the area of a Euclidean 2D convex polygon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry):

> Consider an N-sided spherical polygon and let $A_n$ denote the $n$-th
> interior angle. The area of such a polygon is given by (Todhunter,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry)
> Art.99)
>
> $${\text{Area of polygon (on the unit sphere)}}\equiv E_{N}=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}A_{n}\right)-(N-2)\pi .$$